# How to read a txt file into a 2-dimentional NumPy array character by character?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, txt

I have the following txt file:

```
000120
005000
000900
055000
```

and I want to get a 2 dimensional NumPy array that looks like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]
 [0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0]
 [0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I was trying to use the `np.loadtxt("./file.txt")` function but couldn't get anywhere. Any idea how I could do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Functions like `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt` expect nonempty delimiter/separator used to separate values.
In your case you need to additionally split values on each line to get numpy array. Use the following approach (with [`numpy.fromiter`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html#numpy.fromiter)):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    arr = np.stack([np.fromiter(line.strip(), dtype=np.int64) for line in f])
    print(arr)
```

---

```
[[0 0 0 1 2 0]
 [0 0 5 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 9 0 0]
 [0 5 5 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy's string manipulation functions:

```
import numpy as np

# read the file contents into a list
with open('./file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# remove any leading/trailing white spaces and convert each line to a list of characters
lines = [list(line.strip()) for line in lines]

# convert the list of lists to a NumPy array
arr = np.array(lines)

# convert the character array to a numeric array, replacing any non-numeric characters with zeros
arr = np.where(np.char.isdigit(arr), arr, '0').astype(int)

# print the resulting 2D array
print(arr)
```